# Scaling a cup to have a certain filling volume

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I created a cup in Autodesk Inventor using lathe/rotation, ie I defined the profile and rotated it around an axis. I measured it's volume. By using Patch and Sculpt I filled the inner volume(which would be water) and measured the whole volume. Then I subtracted the cup's volume from the cup volume + water volume and I got the water volume.

In my case 128 ml.

I want to have 250 ml inner volume.

Can I achieve this by multiplying every length with 1.953125?

How and using which factor do I scale my profile uniformly to finally have 250 ml filling volume?

Comment: Volume goes by length cubed. If you multiply every length by a scaled factor, it's almost as if we scale the differential by a constant. If we're scaling by factor $S$, then 
$\int \int \int dx dy dz$ becomes $\int \int \int (Sdx) (Sdy) (Sdz) = S^3 \int \int \int dx dy dz$. Thus, we'd want a factor of $(250/128)^{1/3} = 1.25$.

Answer (score 0):

Is the shape a cylinder?

Seems like, if it was, you could say:

$V_{d}$ is the volume desired of $250$ml and $V_{c}$ is the current volume, $128$ml. Then from the volume of a cylinder, for each case, you could write the ratio as:
$$\frac{V_{d}}{V_{c}}=\frac{h_{d}d^{2}_{d}}{h_{c}d^{2}_{c}},$$ where $d$ and $h$ are the diameter and height of the two cylinders, current and desired. So, then scale the height by $\frac{V_{d}}{V_{c}}=\frac{h_{d}}{h_{c}}=1.953$ or the diameter by $\frac{d_{d}}{d_{c}}=\sqrt{\frac{V_{d}}{V_{c}}}=\sqrt{1.953}=1.398.$

Hope this helps some. Sorry if this isn't exactly what you're looking for.

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Comment: Paul, no, it's more complex than a cylinder.

Comment: Note that this approach (scaling *either* height *or* the diameter) will make the cup "taller" or "fatter" than the original one; which might not be what the original poster desired.

Comment: @PeterKošinár Thanks. I've already noticed that. How would you compensate?

Comment: Clearly the dimension(s) need to increase to hold a larger volume; it will get taller, fatter or a combination of both. I think Zurechtweiser could help by clarifying his/her need.